# Rosetta Stone Challenge: Run-Length Encoding v2.0

Tags: code-golf, string, compression, rosetta-stone

The goal of a Rosetta Stone Challenge is to write solutions in as many languages as possible. Show off your programming multilingualism!

### The Challenge

We've done run-length encoding [be](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1015/8478)[fore](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7320/8478) but only considered runs of a single character. Of course, we can sometimes make even greater savings if we consider runs of multiple characters.

Take `aaaxyzxyzxyzdddd` for instance. This can be compressed to `3a3{xyz}4d`. Your task is to write a program of function which, given a case-sensitive string of letters and spaces, compresses it *optimally* using run-length encoding for multi-character runs.

You may take input via function argument, STDIN or ARGV and return the result or print it to STDOUT.

Runs must not be nested, so `aaabbbaaabbb` must be `3a3b3a3b`, *not* `2{3a3b}`. I.e. the string should be encoded (or decoded) in a single pass.

#### Consequences of Optimal Compression

Some examples where naive application of run-length encoding might lead to suboptimal results:

- `abab` must not be "compressed" to `2{ab}`
- `aaaabcdeabcde` must not be compressed to `4abcdeabcde` but `3a2{abcde}` instead.

If there are two optimal versions (e.g. `aa` and `2a` or `abcabc` and `2{abc}`) either result is fine.

#### Examples

```
Input              Output

aa                 aa -or- 2a
aaaaaAAAAA         5a5A
ababa              ababa
abababa            a3{ba} -or- 3{ab}a
foo foo bar        2{foo }bar
aaaabcdeabcde      3a2{abcde}
xYzxYz             xYzxYz -or- 2{xYz}
abcabcdefcdef      abcab2{cdef}
pppqqqpppqqq       3p3q3p3q
pppqqqpppqqqpppqqq 3{pppqqq}
```

### Scoring

Each language is a separate competition as to who can write the shortest entry, but the overall winner would be the person who wins the most of these sub-competitions. This means that a person who answers in many uncommon languages can gain an advantage. Code golf is mostly a tiebreaker for when there is more than one solution in a language: the person with the shortest program gets credit for that language.

If there is a tie, the winner would be the person with the most second-place submissions (and so on).

### Rules, Restrictions, and Notes

Please keep all of your different submissions contained within a single answer.

Also, no shenanigans with basically the same answer in slightly different language dialects. I will be the judge as to what submissions are different enough.

### Current Leaderboard

This section will be periodically updated to show the number of languages and who is leading in each.

- C# (265) — edc65
- JavaScript (206) — edc65
- Python (214) — Will
- VB.NET (346) — edc65

### Current User Rankings

1. edc65 (3)
2. Will (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (E6) 206

Almost sure it is optimal. I start trying to encode the longest string with the max gain, and recursively encode what remains at left and right. After each try I keep the shortest result.

Golf notes (JS specific)

- Pseudo arguments instead of locals (for recursion)
- Compare lengths using out of bounds index that gives 'undefined'

```javascript
R=(s,n=s,d=s.length>>1,w,i,j,c)=>{
  for(;d;--d){
    for(i=-1;s[d+d+i++];){
      w=s.slice(i,j=i+d);
      for(r=1;w==s.substr(j,d);j+=d)++r;
      c=d>1?r+'{'+w+'}':r+w,
      // c[d*r-1]|| /* uncomment this line (+10 bytes) to have faster response
      n[(c=R(s.slice(0,i))+c+R(s.slice(j))).length]&&(n=c)
    }
  }
  return n
}
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
;['aa','aaaaaAAAAA','ababa','abababa','foo foo bar', 'aaaabcdeabcde',
  'xYzxYz', 'abcabcdefcdef', 'pppqqqpppqqq','pppqqqpppqqqpppqqq']
.forEach(x=>console.log(x+' -> '+R(x)))
```

*Output*

```
aa -> aa
aaaaaAAAAA -> 5a5A
ababa -> ababa
abababa -> 3{ab}a
foo foo bar -> 2{foo }bar
aaaabcdeabcde -> 3a2{abcde}
xYzxYz -> xYzxYz
abcabcdefcdef -> abcab2{cdef}
pppqqqpppqqq -> 3p3q3p3q
pppqqqpppqqqpppqqq -> 3{pppqqq}
```

## C# (.NET 4.0) 265

Exactly the same algorithm

```CS
string R(string s)
{
  string n=s,c,w;
  int l=s.Length,d=l/2,i,j,r;
  for(;d>0;--d)
  {
    for(i=0;d+d+i<=l;i++)
    {
      w=s.Substring(i,d);
      for(j=i+d,r=1;j+d<=l&&w==s.Substring(j,d);j+=d)++r;
      c=d>1?r+"{"+w+"}":r+w;
      // if(c.Length<d*r){ // uncomment this line for faster execution
        c=R(s.Substring(0,i))+c+R(s.Substring(j));
        n=c.Length<n.Length?c:n;
      //} // and this one of course
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

**Test** in LinqPad, mode 'C# program', add a main after the R function

```
void Main()
{
  string[] test = {"aa","aaaaaAAAAA","ababa","abababa","foo foo bar","aaaabcdeabcde",
  "xYzxYz","abcabcdefcdef","pppqqqpppqqq","pppqqqpppqqqpppqqq"};
  test.Select(x => new { x, r=R(x) }).Dump("Result");
}
```

Same Output

## VB.Net (.NET 4) 346 (probably)

Same algorithm and same library, but the language is different enough

I can't be sure about byte count, as Visual Studio keep reformatting the code and adding spaces.

Golf notes: better use something else

```VB
function R(s as string)

  dim n=s,c,w
  dim l=s.Length,i,j,d
  for d=l\2 to 1 step-1
    for i=0 to l-d-d
      w=s.Substring(i,d)
      j=i+d
      r=1
      do while (j+d<=l andalso w=s.Substring(j,d))
        r=r+1
        j=j+d
      loop
      c=if(d>1,r & "{" & w & "}",r & w)
      if(c.Length<d*r) then
        c=R(s.Substring(0,i))+c+R(s.Substring(j))
        if c.Length<n.Length then n=c
      end if
    next
  next
  return n

end function
```

Comment: You can undo the adding of spaces.  If you type a character that makes it reformat hit ctrl-z to just undo the formatting.  It means two characters instead of one every so often but it's better than removing all the spaces and linefeeds afterward.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 214

```python
def t(s):
 b=s;l=len;r=range(1,l(s))
 for i in r:
  p=s[:i];b=min(b,p+t(s[i:]),key=l);x=1
  for j in r:k=i*j+i;x*=p==s[i*j:k];b=min(b,(b,''.join((`j+1`,"{"[i<2:],p,"}"[i<2:],t(s[k:]))))[x],key=l)           
 return b
```

(second level indent is tab)

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), this is the naive recursive approach without early-exit, so its really really slow.