# Binary Run-Length Encoding

Tags: code-golf, binary

## Overview

> Run-length encoding — sequences in which the same data value occurs in many consecutive data elements are stored as a single data value and count

When using [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding):

```
Input:  ABBBCCACB
Output: 1A3B2C1A1C1B
```

This sample has an output that is larger than the input.

---

Instead, it can be simplified for binary inputs by removing the data value in the result,

```
Input:  10001110101
Output: 1331111
```

which is significantly smaller. This works because, logically, if the there is a "next subset" then it must be of a different data value than the current subset. Since there are only two possible values (1 and 0), you always know the "next" data value subset.

---

## Challenge

Implement binary run-length encoding demonstrated above.

- Take input through STDIN or suitable alternative.
- Output to STDOUT or suitable alternative.

---

## Examples

```
In:  101011101011000011
Out: 11113111242

In:  01001010001
Out: 11211131

In:  000000000
Out: 9
```

You may assume that no subsets will be longer than 9 characters (there won't be 10 adjacent zeroes).

Comment: There is an error in your first example's output! The 1 digit after the first B shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AlexA.: I don't see where conversion to binary will actually happen, and besides, I think that the shortest way to run-length encode a binary string will be appreciably different from regular run-length encoding. There might be some tricks or the like available w.r.t. binary that isn't there for other inputs.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman Answers from the other challenge can be copied verbatim and be valid for this challenge, making this a duplicate.

Comment: So it's not encoded whether the string starts with 0 or 1?

Comment: For the purposes of this challenge, no. @xnor

Comment: @AlexA.: Answers from the [linked duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/run-length-encoding) wouldn't be valid here; they print the values as well as the counts.  For example, the top answer in `sh` is built around `uniq -c` with space-separated outputs. Dropping every other character of its output would take extra code, or motivate a different approach.  It's a very similar challenge (and not very practical because of the impossibility of encoding a run longer than 9 bits, unless you allow a `0` count?), but your argument for it being a duplicate seems totally flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth - 5 bytes

```
hMrz8
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hMrz8&input=10001110101%0A01001010001%0A000000000&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>37</s> 29 bytes

```rb
->s{s.gsub(/0+|1+/){$&.size}}
```

Test:

```rb
->s{s.gsub(/0+|1+/){$&.size}}["10001110101"]
=> "1331111"
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes with global variable magic: `->s{s.gsub(/0+|1+/){$&.size}}`

Comment: Ah, of course! Neat, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

## Stuck, 5 bytes

```
soT]y
```

Takes a binary string as input and outputs an array.

### Explanation

```
soT]y

s       get input string
 o      run-level encoding
  T     zip
   ]    flatten
    y   pops the data values off
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
le`s2%
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=le%60s2%25&input=101011101011000011).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 39 bytes

```
import Data.List
(show.length=<<).group
```

Unfortunately `group` is in `Data.List`, so I need the `import`.

Usage example: `(show.length=<<).group $ "101011101011000011"` -> 
`"11113111242"`.